# Storing/Updating Transient Secrets for oAuth with Xero

Tags: apex, oauth2, xero

I am writing a simple Apex class that pulls in some information from Xero to create a new invoice in Salesforce. The problem is that Xero only allows 3-legged oauth, which means I can't just store static access tokens that never change. Instead I need to automatically (i.e. in the apex) store *and* update transient access/refresh tokens in Salesforce to avoid user interaction. Salesforce recommends storing secrets in custom protected metadata or custom protected setting:

https://developer.salesforce.com/wiki/secure_coding_storing_secrets

I went with custom protected metadata because the Xero access token is 1400 characters long and custom settings have max of 255 per field.

However... long story short, custom protected metadata is a huge pain to update. I'm using `Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment` to update the access and refresh tokens if they are expired, but this is *occasionally* causing an exception: `DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object: Invoice__c`. I assume this is because I'm performing an `upsert` on an `Invoice__c` in the same transaction and the asynchronous nature of `enqueueDeployment` means it will sometimes happen before and sometimes happen after `upsert`?

How can I prevent this from happening? I read something about using `@future` but I also read that if the initial transaction is rolled back the future is never called which is a big problem since not writing out an updated refresh or access token means the next transaction won't be able to access Xero.

Any tips? Should I just use a custom setting and just split the access token across 6 different fields and concatenate them at runtime?

Comment: storing in MDT is async and thus by definition, if another Txn needs to access Xero while the MDT deploy was pending, that Txn would fail.

Comment: For our setup, we made a custom object, encrypted with Salesforce shield, and refresh the tokens in there with apex jobs that run at some interval that's less than the token expiration time, so the tokens are updated in the background. Salesforce is a wasteland in terms of secrets management (and general engineering)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up using custom protected settings and split the access token across six 255-byte text fields...

Comment: That's a good feature to know about, but correct me if I'm wrong - I believe with named credentials I would still need to manually authenticate with Xero (in a pop up window or something) every time access token is expired, correct? Whereas with my solution, the salesforce user never needs to manually authenticate with Xero

Comment: If Salesforce correctly manages refresh tokens so that login only needs to happen once, then Named Credentials is clearly the superior solution and we can close this question. I'll test it out

Comment: I refactored (again) to use Auth Providers and Named Credentials, which seem to be the most elegant way of managing OAuth 2.0 tokens (vs. my previous solution of manually managing them). In some ways it's nice to know both methods can work